# Simple server-to-server authentication protocol

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, digital-signature, hmac

I'm new to server authentication. I'd like a simple way to have a server `Main` receive REST commands (GET, POST, etc.) from other servers (e.g., `A` and `B`) in a secure manner.

I read about oAuth2 and oAuth1.0a but I think having a "resource" server and refresh tokens, etc. is an overkill. The simplest two ways I could find are:

- Have servers `A` and `B` generate a key pair, give the public keys to the server `Main` beforehand (or have it accessible through a `/publickey` route), use digital signatures to sign a nonce every time an HTTP request goes from `A->Main` or `B->Main`, and have `Main` check if the DS is correct.
- Do the above, but use symmetric keys, IDs and HMACs (i.e., `Main` knows that `A` has key `XXX`, so when it receives a request claiming it's from `A`, it'll run an HMAC on the received nonce and compare it with the received HMAC)

Please assume that all of the above is done over HTTP, so MITM is a true issue

I found the following references that point to something similar, but **I'd really like an 'official' protocol, that's vetted and guaranteed to be cryptographically-sane**:

- https://wiki.c2.com/?HmacUserAuthentication
- https://github.com/acquia/http-hmac-spec
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a modified version of [Amazon AWS S3 service API authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html). This works just fine. The cost is that there's an HMAC calculated with every request, and the request body has to be used twice.